# How to Set Initial Conditions for Recursive Function with Two Parameters (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm working through *Learn You a Haskell For Great Good* and was trying to work through some example problems for the chapter on recursion.

I'm trying to write a function that takes a lower bound "a" and an upper bound "b" and returns the sum of all the numbers in between, inclusive.

I originally tried (what I thought was) a straight forward approach

```
sumInts :: Int -> Int -> Int
sumInts a a = a 
sumInts a b = (sumInts (a) (b-1)) + b
```

When I tried to compile, I got an error statement

> • Conflicting definitions for ‘a’

I ultimately just wanted the thing to work, so I split up what was supposed to be one function into two.

```
sumInts' :: Int -> Int
sumInts' 0 = 0
sumInts' a = sumInts' (a-1) + a


sumInts :: Int -> Int -> Int
sumInts 0 b = sumInts' b 
sumInts a b = (sumInts (a-1) (b)) - (a-1)
```

I tried searching for what you'd think would be a pretty simple problem. Alas, it seems too niche to pull results.

How do I combine the two function I currently have into one function? Additionally, why didn't my original function work? Any tips on how to avoid this in the future? Thanks!

Comment: also good rule of thumb is don't pass arguments that never change in your recursion. Instead use a `where` clause and reference the constant value bound higher up: `sumInts lo = go where go hi = if hi <= lo then hi else hi + go (hi-1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern matching in Haskell is *linear*. It means that no variable can be written twice in the head of the function (the pattern matching part). So your clause:

```
sumInts a a = a
```

Is not allowed. In that case, you can **use guards**:

```
sumInts :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a
sumInts a b | a <= b = a + sumInts (a+1) b
            | otherwise = 0
```

The guards are conditions after the pipe character (`|`). In case the conditions are satisfied, the function evaluates to the part on the right side of the equal sign (`=`). The `otherwise` is just an alias for `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is about recursion, but the easiest way to use only one function is to not use recursion at all, but a simple mathematical formula.

```
sumInts :: Int -> Int -> Int
sumInts a b = ((a + b) / 2) * (b - a + 1)
```

Comment: I think this formula is incorrect. `sumInts 5 6` should be `11`, but this function returns `0`.

Comment: In this formula `b` is supposed to be the smaller number, not the larger one.

Comment: @amalloy Yes, that's true. I edited it to reflect the original function.